error importing rpy2 and pandas into vscode
import rpy2.robjects as robjects from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri import pandas as pd
above are the relevant lines of code
here are the error messages i'm getting
Import "rpy2.robjects" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated! i  already tried fixing my python interpreter version and updated it to the most recent, but that doesn't seem to have fixed anything. i also made sure both pandas and rpy2 were installed, so i don't think that's the issue either

I would suggest you try the following:

check if both rpy2 and pandas are installed in the same Python environment
try to reinstall the libraries
or just restarting VScode might help to solve the problem

